# Simulate button Cancel on Excel "Save changes" pop up

Tags: excel, vba, popup, sap-gui

I'm trying to automate a SAP transaction using a VBA script. The transaction extracts some data to an Excel template, displays the resulting Excel file and for some reason tries to exit it which shows the "save changes" pop up window, this is where the transaction ends.

I want my VBA code to click "cancel" on the save changes pop up window.

I want my VBA execute this transaction on different items and save the resulting `.xls` files to a specific location, the problem is this pop up window stops the code and I have to click it manually.

Disabling the Pop up will not help as the file will exit without saving and will be lost. I don't have authorization to change the SAP code so my only option is to run a script through VBA.

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force a workbook to save changes, type the following code in a Visual Basic module of that workbook:

```
Sub Auto_Close()

    If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save 
    End If

End Sub
```

This subprocedure checks to see if the file Saved property has been set to False. If so, the workbook has been changed since the last save, and those changes are saved.

SOURCE: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/-how-to-suppress-save-changes-prompt-when-you-close-a-workbook-in-excel-189a257e-ec1b-40f7-9195-56d82e673071?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: This have two problems in my case, the first being that the pop up stops any macro in excel second is the file opens in a different excel instance

Comment: Where does the Excel file come from? Is there a template somewhere? Or is it generated dynamically?

Comment: Perfect! You add this code to the template. `Auto_Close` runs automatically when the workbook is closed. This will force it to happen every time regardless of where or how that workbook is opened.

Comment: I'm sorry that the OP said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67443553/dealing-with-excel-save-changes-pop-up-opening-in-another-instance-and-halting) "The solution in the other thread [your answer] did work but it's not reliable, for some reason it doesn't work most of the time". That would be helpful if you can assist him.

Comment: @SandraRossi I'm not sure what you expect here. This is the VBA solution. What is being asked for is different behavior from SAP, which you cannot change from VBA. You would need SAP development team to give you insight in to how SAP works.