# dealing with excel "Save Changes" pop up opening in another instance and halting my code

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I had this Issue a while back [VBA Code stops when "Save changes" dialog pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62286702/simulate-button-cancel-on-excel-save-changes-pop-up). The answer I got to that question did not work as expected.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is to pull some data from SAP Using VBA.
The only problem is that the extracted data starts automatically another Excel instance and the "Save Changes" pop up window appears, so the code stops until I close it.

The solutions I tried and did not work include:

- Using `AutoClose` or `AutoOpen` subs in the Excel template. I think the reason is the SAP program is the one telling Excel to quit.
- Using VBS to press the key "OK" or "cancel" (`sendkey`) after it appears, which did not work also.

I have searched everywhere for a solution and I did not find my answer yet.

Edit: I fear my question was not clear enough, all my code does is to press a button on SAP, the problem happens with the SAP transaction which opens another instance of excel and shows the pop up, mean while the VBA code is still waiting for the SAP to finish to go to the next line of code, which never happens until I manually close the pop up.

Comment: That's not really the right approach. If the extracted data opens in another instance of Excel, then set an object to that instance so you can prevent the popup in the first place.

Comment: Ok, how can I do that?

Comment: Well it really depends on the code you are using that causes the new instance to open, and you did not include any of that code in your question.

Comment: If you are saying that your old same question was answered but was not solved, why don't you continue with that old question? I propose to close this current question as duplicate. Please add a comment below the old answer that it doesn't solve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simulate button Cancel on Excel "Save changes" pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62286702/simulate-button-cancel-on-excel-save-changes-pop-up)

Comment: I don't have access to the code, it runs from SAP, which I don't have access to view.

Comment: The solution in the other thread did work but it's not reliable, for some reason it doesn't work most of the time.that's why I did close it in the first place but it didn't work out so I had to find another way

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), otherwise this question cannot be answered if it can't be reproduced.

Comment: Please open a support ticket with SAP. This is not a support forum.

Answer (score 1):

Add "Application.DisplayAlerts = False" in the beginning and end (True) of your code to supress the user input. Hereunder an example function that will save as csv but it should get you on track:

```
    Function ExportCSV(arr As Variant, filename As String) As Long
        Dim Newwb As Workbook, sh As Worksheet
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'don't ask, if CSV exists overwrite
        
            Set Newwb = Workbooks.Add
            With Newwb.ActiveSheet
                .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2))).Value2 = arr
                .SaveAs filename:=filename, FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True 'save as csv using the tabname
            End With
            
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Newwb.Close savechanges:=False 'close the file
    End Function
```

best of luck,

ceci